# How to Create a directory with share option "Full Control"

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Here i have a problem, which is i'm cannot share the directory were i create. The directory is created successfully, but it cannot share. Whenever i select the properties of the created folder in share tab "Everyone" is added but it not share, thus other net user is cannot access/see the folder. Can any one help me on this?  Below is shows the code in C# were i do. Thanks.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(filepath))
        {
            Process.Start(filepath);
        }
        else
        {
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath);
            }


            DirectorySecurity sec = Directory.GetAccessControl(filepath);
            SecurityIdentifier everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
            sec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(everyone, FileSystemRights.FullControl | FileSystemRights.Synchronize,
            InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
            Directory.SetAccessControl(filepath, sec);
```

}

Comment: You should almost never share anything with Full Control. Full Control affords users permissions to change the permissions. Read & Modify are enough in 99.99999999% of cases.

Comment: One of my biggest annoyances as a network admin is crappy software manufacturers who insist that their software needs Everyone/Full Control because they dont know and cant be bothered to learn how permissions actually work.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Before this i'm do a batch file to share a folder. is it possible to doing the same in c#. Batch code "net share testfolder=c:\testfolder /GRANT:Everyone,FULL". Thanks.